# How to insert whilst removing rows which do not match the insert values

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to insert/remove a table's rows by comparing existing rows with rows that I wish to insert. Then remove any rows which don't match my 'insert rows' and insert any rows that don't already exist (from my insert values).

I could delete all rows each time and then insert but I wonder if there's a more efficient way?

(data will likely only change by a couple of rows be that removed or added)

For example I may have the values (1, 2, 3, 4, 7) which I wish to insert. The database holds (1, 2, 3, 6) so I would want to remove '6' and insert '4' and '7'. These are keys on the table but would be affected by some WHERE clause.

Also the actual scenario is that a user may have 'items' which belong to them. Their items can change i.e. be added to or removed from and I want all user_items stored in one table where each instance of an item has a unique id.

Comment: three stages: a select with a `where not in (your new values)` to get any "missing" records, insert any missing records, delete the orphaned ones

Comment: @MarcB Thanks buddy, works nicely.

Answer (score 1):

It's the clear and insert routine. Fast and easy.

```
TRUNCATE table;
INSERT INTO table VALUES (blaah);
```

Comment: I'm sorry I should have been more clear - I really meant rows in a table - I'll update my question.